# Storing DateTime into Array in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

I have initialized an array for my `DateTime`.

```
DateTime[] departureCalcArray = new DateTime[10];
```

And then getting the value of the `DateTimePicker` that is formatted as `h:mm tt`(that is 8:30 AM with no preceeding zero) .

My code for storing the value of the `DateTimePicker` is as below.

```
departureCalcArray[i] = timeDeparture.Value.Date;
```

However, when I checked if the value is saved via `MessageBox.Show();` 
I keep getting the date today and 12:00:00 AM. Although back in PHP, I use to convert the time to 24hour format so that I can use it in calculation. Any help please?

Comment: `timeDeparture.Value.Date;` -> `timeDeparture.Value;`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen It still `12:00:00 AM` and I want to format it to 24 hrs so that I can use it for computations.

Comment: piece of advice,  never use DateTime.   Use DateTimeOffset.  Even if you don't think you need to, do it, it will save you a LOT of grief in the long run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
departureCalcArray[i] = timeDeparture.Value.Date;
```

to

```
departureCalcArray[i] = timeDeparture.Value;
```

When you use the [`Date` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx) of a `DateTime` instance, you get a new `DateTime` instance with the same date, but its Time component set to 12:00AM

Comment: I just want to get the time, if that's possible.

Comment: @Fiendcoder1 not entirely sure I understand - if you're not interested in dates but only time, you might want to grab the `TimeOfDay` property and store that in a `TimeSpan[]` instead

Comment: Yes, because I already have a date in a different column of my winform and a departure and arrival column. I have a formula if the user choose 11:59:99 before and 12:00:00 after. So I want just to get the time.

Comment: Hello. I've followed the top answer in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337625/convert-am-pm-time-to-24-hours-format. And I get what exactly what I want, but how can I just store it as `HH:mm`?

Comment: `ToString("HH:mm")`

Comment: I believe I can't do computation to `ToString("HH:mm")`

Comment: @Fiendcoder1 No, it will result in a string. You can't have both - either keep it as a `DateTime` and specify [column formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9x2790s(v=vs.110).aspx) to display `HH:mm`, or convert it to a string at display it directly

Comment: Ok, I'll come back to you later.

Comment: I now understand. I really thought the if you enclose it to `""` it will be a `string`. But after doing some `if else` conditioning. it retains it type of `DateTime`. Thanks man

Comment: Well answered bro :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to comment becos I just started this account. 
This answer is related to a conversation in comments on how to change to HH:mm

```
DateTimePicker.ShowUpDown = true;
DateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "hh:mm";
DateTimePicker.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
```

Credits to here: [DateTime Picker In WinForm How To Pick Time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728116/datetime-picker-in-winform-how-to-pick-time)