# How to set the time in date timepickers in c#

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I'm new to date timepickers. I was wondering if someone could explain them to me properly. I have a booking system that you must be able to book a date and specific time in the future and reserve that time frame in a sql database. Can I do it with date timepickers? It has a nice interface when its on my form but I cant see a way for the user to set the time? it always just gives me the default time. Any help? thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1CbU.jpg

Comment: Can you give us more information?  Win Forms? WPF? Version of .net?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DateTimePicker: pick both date and time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93472/datetimepicker-pick-both-date-and-time)

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: dotnet framework 4. its a booking system to create a extraMathclass for people to go to. this is the admin who is creating the extraclass event with a class location, price, classtype(eg. grade 8 algebra extra class). what i want to use the datetimepicker for is sothat the admin can select a date and a time for the extra class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DateTimePicker-Control has a Format-Property, which will set the format of the date and time displayed in the control.
AS stated  in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93472/datetimepicker-pick-both-date-and-time) you can use following format to show Date and time:

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MM.dd.yyyy hh:mm:ss";
```

Here you can get a list of all format string and their descriptions:
[List of CustomFormat-String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/DE-DE/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx)

The result will look like this:

[image: DateTimePicker Custom Format]

.NET also has a structure called [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) to save your selected value.
You can save it with following code

```
DateTime yourSelectedDateTime  = dateTimePicker1.Value;
textBox1.Text = yourSelectedDateTime.ToString();
```

Comment: thanks :) but what i want to know is there any way in the dateTimepicker to let the user physically define the selected time on the date? or must it be programmed manually into variables?

Comment: Unfortunately you can only pick Dates with the DropDown of the DateTimePicker-Control. But you can raise and decrease every part of date and time with the arrow-keys or if you set the `ShowUpDown = true;` with two buttons (See here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetimepicker-2.png). But if you set ShowUpDown to true you'll have no DropDown-Menu anymore

Answer (score 0):

Date Time pickers are pretty useful to use when you want people to be able to visually select a date/time. once the user selects a datetime, you can access it like this

```
int mymonth = this.datetimepicker1.Value.Month
int myday = this.datetimepicker1.Value.day
```

etc...

Furthermore, you can use events to trigger when stuff happens with them. So for instance, they select a date, you can use the ValueChanged event to make other fun stuff happen too.

Comment: thank you :) but how does the user pick the specific time in the datetimepicker

Comment: added a picture of my form to the post. will that work? where i use your idea of adding a myday, mymonth and myyear and then getting the time manually with comboboxes? isnt there a built in way seeing that its called a dateTIMEpicker:P

Comment: If you set the format to time, then they can choose the time by entering it in, and choose the date by clicking on the day picker icon like normal.

dateTimePicker1.format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time