# Scheduler in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I want a time picker in visual studio, I did find a `DateTimePicker` but turns out it's just a date picker
 [image]

I did something similiar in Qt, I found a time picker there, I need soemthing like this in VS:

[image]

Comment: C++ or C#? Which graphics Framework? And could you formulate an actual question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 datetimepickers to pick date AND time. They can pick Date OR time in WinForms (But not both)
Put a first one with the name of datePortionDateTimePicker
Put a second one and name it timePortionDateTimePicker. 
Then on the form load apply these settings:

```
timePortionDateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
timePortionDateTimePicker.ShowUpDown = true;
```

When you need to combine date AND time use :

```
DateTime myDate = datePortionDateTimePicker.Value.Date + timePortionDateTimePicker.Value.TimeOfDay;
```

More info :

[DateTimePicker: pick both date and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93472/datetimepicker-pick-both-date-and-time)